# Вернуть html сраницу get методом

Tags: spring, get, rest

У меня есть get метод который обрабатывает ссылку типа html_map/{code} где code это ключ к кеше где лежит String с html страницей. как мне вывести ее на экран после отработки get метода.

я использовал

```
String htmlFile = (String) someCache.getObj(code);
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlFile) ;
```

все оке файл формируется. но как верно его вернуть не знаю. может быть сам подход не верный?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/servlet-142430.html

забыл про HttpServletResponse response =))